# Include Sitemap in iFrame to make Quick Site Navigation Bar? Effects on SEO?

Tags: html, seo, navigation, sitemap

I am slowly building a website (which I won't link to so I don't look like I'm just looking for traffic) and I only really have experience with HTML and CSS. I intend on learning PHP, JavaScript, and some other stuff related to web development eventually... but for now I'd like HTML and CSS answers only (including "you're dumb, you can't do that").

Ok, to the point...
I want my site to have a navigation bar (probably along the left side) that doesn't need to be updated for every single page I create. My theory is to set up a search engine friendly sitemap in a separate page and use iFrames to embed that sitemap into all my pages. That way when I update my sitemap, I update my navigation bar on every page. To my ** inexperienced** mind, it seems a simple, effective, and elegant solution.

My questions are: 
How will search engine crawlers view this? I know they don't play well with data in frames but the sitemap is it's own page so crawlers should be able to navigate without problems right? Will this have adverse impacts on how much search engines trust my site (ie hurt my page rank)? Have I lost my marbles by trying to do something incredibly idotic?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated and if I am violating Stackoverflow's rules please tell me and I'll make necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this Google support page to see how to create a manual sitemap. It is explained very well and is easy to follow.
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34657